# Алгоритм организации путей и ссылок на файл

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть страница добавления объявления. На этой странице есть модуль добавления фотографий, который использует Ajax для передачи файлов на сервер(jquery upload file). Один из этапов это добавление фото, **сервер должен записать файлы на диск, а имена файлов в базу данных.**

Если с базой данных все понятно, то насчет путей для файлов **ВОПРОС**: как лучше организовать пространство директорий для файлов конкретного объявления не зная id объявления и id пользователя?

Были мысли писать файлы в отдельную папку типа `temp_photos`, а после подачи объявления, зная id, переместить файлы в текущую директорию. Но, мне кажется, это не рационально, слишком много лишних операций.

Хотелось бы, чтобы файл записывался один раз в одно место и больше ничего с ним не делать. Но нужен определенных алгоритм путей и ссылок на этот файл. Чтобы его можно было потом найти на сервере.

Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Что мешает загружать фото только после того, как уже все поля заполнены и отправлены на сервер? Просто при добавлении фоток (пока не все поля еще заполнены) банально их в разметке отображать (хотя даже это не обязательно), никуда не загружая.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Фото загружаются до подачи объявления для удобства пользователя. Например, он может выбрать перетаскивая в нужное поле главное фото, которое будет отображаться первым в его объявлении с большим размером. Затем производится рендеринг  на сервере, все добавляемые фотки еще до подачи становятся красивыми и ровными. Плюс он может разворачивать фото, если оно сфотографировано в не подходящей ориентации и т.д. Много плюсов.

Comment: Раз у вас фото преобразуется на сервере, то какая разница куда оно изначально загружено. В момент его преобразования заодно перепишите в другую папку. Могу только заметить, что папка куда вы его изначально заливаете не должна быть доступна из вне. переносите в доступную только когда убедитесь, что это действительно картинка. А что до путей - то их совершенно не обязательно привязывать к id пользователя/поста. равномерно раскладывайте в набор папок, что бы в одной не более 1000 файлов было и все

Comment: `все добавляемые фотки еще до подачи становятся красивыми и ровными`  - все эти красивости вполне можно сделать также после заполнения всех полей. Пользователь все равно не знает, что вы там с ними творите, поэтому ему без разницы до или после это будет. А все эти: покрутить фото и прочее вообще вы же все равно на клиенте делаете и пользователю также нет дела были ли фото обрезаны до манипуляций или нет, раз он загружает их уже такими какие есть..... то есть, по факту, достаточно ему позволить дать файлы, поманипулировать ими а всё остальное уже доделать опосля загрузки.... кмк